# $x\in H^2(\mathbb{R})\Rightarrow u(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

By $H^2(\mathbb{R})$ denote the Sobolevspace 
$$
W^{2,2}(\mathbb{R}):=\left\{u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}): D^{\alpha}u\in L^2(\mathbb{R})~\forall\lvert\alpha\rvert\leq 2\right\}
$$
which has an inner product
$$
\langle u,v\rangle_{H^2}:=\sum_{i=0}^2\langle D^iu,D^iv\rangle_{L^2}
$$
and norm
$$
\lVert u\rVert_{H^2}:=\left(\sum_{\lvert\alpha\rvert\leq 2}\lVert D^{\alpha}u\rVert_{L^2}^2\right)^{1/2}.
$$

> > Let $u\in H^2(\mathbb{R})$. Do we then have that $u\to 0$ and $Du\to 0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$?

**idea**

Suppose, $u$ is not tending to zero as $x\to\pm\infty$. Since $\lvert u(x)\rvert^2\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, I think this would imply that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lvert u(x)\rvert^2\, dx = \infty$, contradicting the assumption that $u\in H^2(\mathbb{R})$ since this means that $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lvert u(x)\rvert^2\, dx <\infty$.

Comment: I guess there is a typo in $u \to 0$ and $u_x \to 0$? Idea: Suppose that $u$ would not tend to zero and use the fact that $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @T'x Where do you see a typo and why?

Comment: what do you mean with $u_x$?

Comment: I mean the derivative of u with respect to x.

Comment: Well, only the weak derivative exists. So you should write $u(x) \to 0$ and $Du(x) \to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$.

Comment: Keep in mind that functions in $H^2$ are equivalence classes, so anything like $u(x)$ is not defined. Sorry for my misleading idea, I had the wrong picture in my mind. Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246336/vanishing-at-the-infinity-of-a-function-in-the-sobolev-space) helps you.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand.

Comment: Functions in $L^2$ (an so in $H^2$) are equal, if they are equal almost everywhere. That means for $f \in H^2$ the expression $f(x)$ is not well definied, since we could change the value of $f(x)$, but the integral would be the same.

Comment: Okay. Maybe I am just too stupid, but I still do not see how to prove that for $u\in H^2(\mathbb{R})$, we have that both u and its first weak derivative are vanishing for $x\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: The point is, that they are vanishing in $L^2$ sense. A possible proof is given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246336/vanishing-at-the-infinity-of-a-function-in-the-sobolev-space?noredirect=1&lq=1). As I said above $u(x) \to 0$ for $x \to \infty$ is not defined. (You first have to choose a smooth representative)

Comment: So let $u\in H^2(\mathbb{R})$. Then there exists some $w\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ with $u=w$ almost everywhere. And then?

Answer (score 1):

We use the following result, which is classical and proven for example [here in Theorem 3.37](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pde_notes.pdf). See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814779/prove-that-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-ux-0-for-u-in-w1-p-ma/2824461#2824461).

> Let $u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $n<p<\infty$. Then $u \in C_0^{0,1-n/p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $u(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Let $u \in H^2(\mathbb{R})$. In particular $u \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$ and we see that $1=n<p=2$. Thus by applying above theorem we get that $u$ has zero limit as infinity.

Moreover, we have $Du \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$ and by applying above result on $Du$ gives us $Du(x) \to 0$ as $x\to \pm \infty$.

To clarify the comments: Yes, it is important that one says that one identifies $u$ and $Du$ with their continuous representations, so that $u(x)$ and $Du(x)$ are well-defined everywhere.