# Prove that $\lim\limits_{|x|\rightarrow \infty} u(x) = 0$ for $u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n).$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $n < p < \infty$ and $ u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n). $

Prove that $\lim\limits_{|x|\rightarrow \infty} u(x) = 0.$

In the proof I can use that $ C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ is dense in $ W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n). $

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you know Morrey's inequality?

Comment: Yes, can I use it here?

Comment: Morrey's inequality implies that $u$ is actually (Holder) continuous. Can you prove the statement for continuous functions?

Comment: Do you mean $u$ continuous with compact support?

Comment: But then it's clear isn't it?

Comment: No, $u$ need not have compact support. E.g. $u(x) = e^{-x^2}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok, but right now I have no idea how to prove it for $u$ continuous...

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here in these notes by John Hunter.](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pde_notes.pdf) It should be Theorem 3.37 what you are looking for.

> Theorem 3.37. Let $n<p<\infty$ and $\alpha =1-n/p$. Then $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \hookrightarrow C_0^{0,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and there is a constant such that $\|f\|_{C^{0,\alpha}} \leq C\|f\|_{W^{1,p}}$ for all $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

The proof goes like this. Let $u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then there exists some $\{u^\epsilon \}_{\epsilon>0}\subset C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $u^\epsilon \to u$ in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. Moreover, we have
$|u^\epsilon(x)-u^\epsilon(y)| \leq C|x-y|^{1-n/p}\|D u^\epsilon\|_{L^p}$ 
for all $x,y$ and hence
$|u(x)-u(y)| \leq C|x-y|^{1-n/p}\|D u\|_{L^p}$
for all $x,y$ (by choosing the continuous representation of $u$). Also, $u$ is the uniform limit of a compactly supported function and hence $u(x) \to 0$ as $x\to \pm \infty$.